# How could I send a mail without using from mail credential

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendmail

How could I send a mail without using from mail credential like E-mail ID and Password using  Local-host?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a folder called "maildrop" on your c:/ drive and use the following in your Web.config file:

```
<mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod='SpecifiedPickupDirectory'>
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\maildrop" />
    </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

More information:

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/05/27/asp-net-using-pickup-directory-for-outgoing-e-mails.aspx

For external delivery without credentials:

```
<mailSettings>
    <smtp from="info@mysite.com">
        <network host="smtp.myhost.com"/>
    </smtp>
</mailsettings>
```

Comment: with this code I can save mail in my personal computer or server  but i can't send it to any specific email address. Can you tell me who can I do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

use this code for that,

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    try
    {
    MailAddress SendFrom = new MailAddress(txtFrom.Text);
    MailAddress SendTo = new MailAddress(txtTo.Text);

    MailMessage MyMessage = new MailMessage(SendFrom, SendTo);

    MyMessage.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
    MyMessage.Body = txtBody.Text;

    Attachment attachFile = new Attachment(txtAttachmentPath.Text);
    MyMessage.Attachments.Add(attachFile);

    SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient(txtSMTPServer.Text);
    emailClient.Send(MyMessage);

    litStatus.Text = "Message Sent";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    litStatus.Text=ex.ToString();
    }
    }
```